# Image display blank upon being updated

Tags: python, kivy

I am using a timer to update the image on the UI after every second. After starting the UI the first image is being displayed. After the timer thread kicks in to display the next image, the widget is displayed blank (i cannot see the image). I can see the image if i start the index from a different value. I do not have an issue with the images. I am unable to update the image on the UI screen. Can anyone help me figure out the issue?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty
import json, timer
import threading

data = json.load(open('demotest.json'))

Builder.load_file('dv_demo.kv')


class DVDemo(Widget):
    message = StringProperty()
    image = StringProperty('')
    sms = ListProperty()
    idx = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DVDemo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update_data_index(self.idx)

    def schedule_screens(self):
        self.idx = self.idx + 1
        if self.idx >= len(data):
            time.sleep(500)
        temp = threading.Thread(target=self.update_data_index, args=(self.idx,))
        threading.Timer(1, temp.start).start()

    def update_data_index(self, idx):
        # self.image = data[idx]['picture_url']
        self.message = data[idx]['message']
        self.sms = data[idx]['sms']

        message_layout = self.ids.message_panel
        message_btn = Button(text=self.message, background_color=[0, 1, 1, 1])
        message_layout.add_widget(message_btn)

        sms_layout = self.ids.sms_panel
        sms_layout.clear_widgets()
        for sms_msg in self.sms:
            sms_btn = Button(text=sms_msg['sms'], background_color=[0, 0, 2, 1])
            sms_layout.add_widget(sms_btn)

        self.ids.image_object.source = data[idx]['picture_url']

        self.schedule_screens()


class DVDemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'DV Demo App'
        return DVDemo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DVDemoApp().run()
```

```
<ColoredLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'top'
    padding: 4, 4
    bold: True
    color: (.6, .6, .6, 1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: (.9, .9, .9)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.width - sp(2), self.height - sp(2)

<DVDemo>:
    FloatLayout:
        id: demo_panels
        size: root.width - 50, root.height - 50
        pos: root.x + 25, root.y + 25

        BoxLayout:
            id: message_panel
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: (.9, .9, .9)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.width - sp(2), self.height - sp(2)

        #ColoredLabel:
        #    id: message_panel
        #    text: root.message
        #    pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
        #    size_hint: 0.5, 1

        BoxLayout:
            id: image_panel
            #text: "Image"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":1}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            Image:
                id: image_object
                source: root.image
                center_x: self.parent.center_x
                center_y: self.parent.center_y
                size: self.parent.height,self.parent.width

        BoxLayout:
            id: sms_panel
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.5}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: (.9, .9, .9)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.width - sp(2), self.height - sp(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the GUI properties must be done on the main thread. Conveniently, there is a `Clock.schedule_once()` method that schedules a call on the main thread after a delay. So, I would suggest modifying part of the `DVDemo` class as:

```
class DVDemo(Widget):
    message = StringProperty()
    image = StringProperty('')
    sms = ListProperty()
    idx = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DVDemo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update_data_index()

    def schedule_screens(self):
        self.idx = self.idx + 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_data_index, 5)

    def update_data_index(self, *args):
        idx = self.idx
        .
        .
        .
```

The above code uses `Clock.schedule_once()` and eliminates the passing of `idx` among methods, since it is an attribute of the `DVDemo` instance.